# Redux store NextJS config throws window not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I added the code below, somehow it throws an error saying ReferenceError: window is not defined

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducer";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1):

First install the dependencies using npm.

```
npm install redux-devtools-extension
```

Now write this code for redux dev tools

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { promiseMiddleware } from '@adobe/redux-saga-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
```

```
let composeWithDevTools;
composeWithDevTools = require('redux-devtools-extension').composeWithDevTools;

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware, thunk, sagaMiddleware))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing React Dev tools from chrome webstore

Comment: dont think its to do with react dev tools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).